# mysql how to dump all table structure for a database and import into another

Tags: mysql

From the command line, how do I export all table structure in a mysql database and import into another.  I dont need the table...just to create new tables in a new database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqldump with the no-data option should do what you want.

`mysqldump --no-data`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data